# Emulating crypto currencies cold storage using Tails + disconnected computer?

Tags: bitcoin

Problem:  I need cold storage protection for crypto currencies while traveling.  I'll only have 1 computer.

Does this solution work?

Tails on an SD card that is only ever inserted into hardware when the computer is off & disconnected from the internet.

If Tails is booted with persistent storage enabled, is there any vector for which a password entered to open an encrypted vault and/or wallet is leaked thru Bios or any other vector when the computer is later booted to another OS connected to the Internet?

Is there anyway for that entered password to end up in some kind of hardware input capture & later broadcast when booted to another internet connected OS?

Comment: Well naturally if the BIOS is malicious, then anything running on the computer is unsafe.

Comment: If the BIOS is booted to Tails, is there a way it could capture data & broadcast it when it is later booted to an OS that is connected to the internet?

Comment: In theory, yes.